# Search a matrix for rows with given values in any order

Tags: r

I have a matrix and a vector with values:

```
mat<-matrix(c(1,1,6,
              3,5,2,
              1,6,5,
              2,2,7,
              8,6,1),nrow=5,ncol=3,byrow=T)

vec<-c(1,6)
```

This is a small subset of a N by N matrix and 1 by N vector. Is there a way so that I can subset the rows with values in vec?

The most straight forward way of doing this that I know of would be to use the subset function:

```
subset(mat,vec[,1] == 1 & vec[,2] == 6) #etc etc
```

The problem with subset is you have to specify in advance the column to look for and the specific combination to do for. The problem I am facing is structured in a way such that I want to find all rows containing the numbers in "vec" in any possible way. So in the above example, I want to get a return matrix of:

```
1,1,6
1,6,5
8,6,1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bad example for three reasons: 1) you say your larger case has a N-by-N matrix and a N-long vector, so why doesn't your example? 2) the expected output is the same whether you have to match one of the values or all of them. You accepted Ricardo's answer's without noticing that his code was returning rows were only one value was matched... Now fixed. 3) You are not describing the particular case where `vec` would contain the same value more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(vec %in% x))
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

but this may give you unexpected results if `vec` contains repeated values:

```
vec <- c(1, 1)
apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(vec %in% x))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

so you would have to use something more complicated using `table` to account for repetitions:

```
vec <- c(1, 1)
is.sub.table <- function(table1, table2) {
  all(names(table1) %in% names(table2)) &&
  all(table1 <= table2[names(table1)])
}
apply(mat, 1, function(x)is.sub.table(table(vec), table(x)))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However, if the vector length is equal to the number of columns in your matrix as you seem to indicate but is not the case in your example, you should just do:

```
vec <- c(1, 6, 1)
apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(sort(vec) == sort(x)))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I edited as I don't think you understood the question properly. OP wants to find rows where *all* numbers from `vec` are found, not *one*. Feel free to rollout if it's me who don't understand.

Comment: @flodel, interesting.. no I didn't get that at all.  The only indication I see of that is the OP's use of `&` which I tossed up to incorrect use.  But in fact, you may be right

Comment: Sorry, my vector would never contain repeated values as they are actually combinations of index numbers. I should have provided a clearer sample question.